# i have '__contains__' ,why error

Tags: python

```
class a(object):
    def a(self):
        return True
    __contains__=a

b=a()
print 2 in b#why error
```

Comment: Please: when you get an error, include the error in the question.

Comment: Also, it is best practice to include spaces around your `=` signs in assignments (though not necessarily in function arguments), and before comments. The code looks kind of jammed together.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`__contains__` is meant to take an argument. `a` doesn't accept an argument.

The following is your example with a working `__contains__`:

```
>>> class a(object):
...     def a(self, item):
...         return True
...     __contains__=a
...
>>> b=a()
>>> print 2 in b
True
```

Answer (score 3):

The signature of `__contains__` is:

`object.__contains__(self, item)`

as per [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__). You need to extend your "a" method:

`def a(self, item)`

```
class a(object):
    def a(self, item):
        return True
    __contains__=a
```